# Generating Table Content with TWIG in for loop

Tags: symfony, twig

I've got a table, that content got generated in a twig template. Every column that got generated executes the code below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got what the criteria is exactly, but what about this:

http://twigfiddle.com/ksgpf8

```
{% for key, value in data %}
    <span class="uk-icon-{{ key == page.id and value > 0 ? 'check' : 'close' }}"><span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Then your code is wrong. As you can see this works on the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

How about;

```
{% if moto is defined %}
    {# check if moto has a value, as per your nothing in?? #}
    {% for key,cache in moto %}
        {% if key != page.id %}
             {# page id not equal to key, so just show close #}
             <span class="uk-icon-close"><span>
        {% else %}
            {# page id is equal to key, so check cache #}
            {% if cache > 0 %}
                {# cache good, so show check #}
                <span class="uk-icon-check"><span>
            {% else %}
               {# cache good, so show close #}
               <span class="uk-icon-close"><span>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```